# Comparing within-subject z-scores (survey data)

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, standard-error, standardization, z-statistic

I have some messy survey data, wherein one group of interest (cut on one self-reported behavior) rated every single attribute  (7-point Likert scales) higher than any other group. I think this has more to do with survey-taking style than the actual variables of interest.

To correct for survey-taking style, I calculated within-subject z-scores. That is, I standardized each subject's score on each question to that same subject's mean & SD score across every other question.

I have two questions:

1.) Is this a valid way of looking at the problem?
2.) Can I compare one group's mean z-scores on any given question with another group's mean z-scores on that same question (e.g., plotting the means and SEs and eyeballing it or a quick t-test; not necessarily anything too involved)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This has been driving me bonkers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues to consider, e.g.:

1. Is there really a need to standardize?
2. Is the standard deviation valid as a measure of dispersion for your data, e.g., are the distributions symmetric?
3. How would you interpret the result since it's no longer on the scale people understand?
4. How will you take the uncertainty in the standard deviation estimates into account in any formal analysis?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer to both your questions depends on how you plan to interpret the results.  My guess is that the answer is both questions is, probably not.  Concerning question 2, likely the means will be about zero, given the standardization process you used.

Can you provide more information about what you are doing and why you think the one scale point difference is an artifact rather than a real effect?